# Kotlin, Android platform. How to check if the text contains any numbers/symbols/chars?

Tags: android, kotlin

For starters, I am new to Kotlin and have only been working with Android Studio for 2 weeks.

I'm just trying to check if the EditText field contains any digits/symbols/chars.
I tried writing it like this:

```
    if (editText!!.text.contains(Int)) {
    textView?.text = "ERROR! EDITTEXT FIELD CONTAINS DIGITS!"
}
```

But it doesn't work like that. How can i check, if text is numeric or not, or maybe contains symbols (like "/?!:;%") for example? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to check if it contains any numbers, or if it contains _only_ numbers?

Comment: Yes, if it contains ANY numbers. Or symbols, or chars. I know how to check if text contains some word, like 'editText!!.text.contains("abcd")', but i don't know how to check if it contains ANY numbers/chars/symbols. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is going to be different depending on what you're looking for.  Generally, you could use a regex, but what the regex is will depend on if you want numbers, characters, or symbols.

Comment: Well, i type in EditText field some text, and i want to check if it contains any digits. For example: "qwerty" - textView?.setText( "OK"), "qwer4ty" - textView?.setText( "NOT OK")

Comment: `if (editText.text.any { it.isDigit() }) {... } `

Answer (score 12):

Uppercase letters:

```
if (yourString.contains("[A-Z]".toRegex())) {
    //do something
}
```

Lowercase letters:

```
if (yourString.contains("[a-z]".toRegex())) {
    //do something
}
```

Numbers:

```
if (yourString.contains("[0-9]".toRegex())) {
    //do something
}
```

Special characters:

```
if (yourString.contains("[!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;\\\\<=>?@\\[\\]^_`{|}~]".toRegex())) {
    //do something
}
```

All above characters:

```
if (yourString.contains("[A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;\\\\<=>?@\\[\\]^_`{|}~]".toRegex())) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you need to check if the text contains only letters or not, rather than using a regex for any digits/special characters, you can use a regex with a negation on letters `[^A-Za-z]`, which would mean **anything other than letters**. So your logic would be

```
if (editText!!.text.contains(Regex("[^A-Za-z]"))) {
    textView?.text = "ERROR! EDITTEXT FIELD CONTAINS DIGITS/SPECIAL CHARS!"
}
```

Note that this considers only the English letters.

Answer (score 2):

Define a string that contains all the symbols and digits that you want to check:

```
val symbols = "0123456789/?!:;%"
```

and then use `any`:

```
if (editText!!.text.any {it in symbols}) {
    textView?.text = "ERROR! EDITTEXT FIELD CONTAINS DIGITS/INVALID SYMBOLS!"
}
```